# Jquery plus and minus symbol toggle

Tags: jquery

I am using the following syntax on my menu.

```
<div id="flip5"><a href="#">Demo <span id="togglebut">+</span></a></div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to toggle the + to a - when user clicks on the link.

The link opens up a hidden div.

So far I have got to the below code but it's not really a toggle.

```
$("flip5").click(function(){
  $("togglebut").html("-");
});
```

any help here?

Comment: Some if/else would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the HTML already is `"+"`, if it is change it to `"-"`, and vice versa :

```
$("#flip5").click(function(){
    $("#togglebut").html(function(_, html) {
        return $.trim(html) == '+' ? '-' : '+';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YVxAb/)

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

How about, assuming your using jquery:

```
$("#flip5").click(function(){
  var $but = $("#togglebut");
  $but.html($but.html() == "+" ? "-" : "+");
});
```

This stores the jquery object for the `#togglebut` span in the `$but` variable, mainly for readability. It then toggles the new value to be the opposite value out of +/- from the last value using the ?: operator.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9s33C/

A more readable version might be:

```
$("#flip5").click(function() {
  var $but = $("#togglebut");

  if($but.html() == "+")
    $but.html("-")
  else
    $but.html("+")
});
```